# How would I go about coding this function for a simplified tic tac toe game?

Tags: python

I'm taking a course, and as our final project, we need to make a simplified tic tac toe. This is my code so far, but I need help with the `DrawMove(board)` function.

```
import random

the_board = [[1,2,3], [4,'X',6], [7,8,9]]
free_fields = [(the_board[0][0]), (the_board[0][1]), (the_board[0][2]), (the_board[1][0]), (the_board[1][1]), (the_board[1][2]), (the_board[2][0]), (the_board[2][1]), (the_board[2][2])]

def DisplayBoard(board):
    print(f"""
    +-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |
    |   {board[0][0]}   |   {board[0][1]}   |   {board[0][2]}   |
    |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |
    |   {board[1][0]}   |   {board[1][1]}   |   {board[1][2]}   |
    |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |
    |   {board[2][0]}   |   {board[2][1]}   |   {board[2][2]}   |
    |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+
    """)

def EnterMove(board):
    move = int(input('What is your move?: '))
    if move == 1:
        board[0][0] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 2:
        board[0][1] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 3:
        board[0][2] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 4:
        board[1][0] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 5:
        board[1][1] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 6:
        board[1][2] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 7:
        board[2][0] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 8:
        board [2][1] = 'O'
        DisplayBoard(board)
    elif move == 9:
        board[2][2] = 'O'  
        DisplayBoard(board)
    else:
        print('Invalid move')
        move = int(input('What is your move?: '))

def MakeListOfFreeFields(board):
    for i in free_fields:
        if type(i) != int:
            free_fields.remove(i)

def VictoryFor(board, sign='O'):
    if the_board[1] == the_board[2] == the_board[3] == sign or the_board[1] == the_board[2] == the_board[3] != sign: # across the top
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over. You won.\n")                                  
    elif the_board[4] == the_board[5] == the_board[6] == sign or the_board[4] == the_board[5] == the_board[6] != sign: # across the middle
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                
    elif the_board[7] == the_board[8] == the_board[9] == sign or the_board[7] == the_board[8] == the_board[9] != sign: # across the bottom
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                
    elif the_board[1] == the_board[4] == the_board[7] == sign or the_board[1] == the_board[4] == the_board[7] != sign: # down the left side
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                
    elif the_board[2] == the_board[5] == the_board[8] == sign or the_board[2] == the_board[5] == the_board[8] != sign: # down the middle
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                
    elif the_board[3] == the_board[6] == the_board[9] == sign or the_board[3] == the_board[6] == the_board[9] != sign: # down the right side
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                 
    elif the_board[1] == the_board[5] == the_board[9] == sign or the_board[1] == the_board[5] == the_board[9] != sign: # diagonal
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                
    elif the_board[3] == the_board[5] == the_board[7] == sign or the_board[3] == the_board[5] == the_board[7] != sign: # diagonal
        DisplayBoard(the_board)
        print("\nGame Over.\n")                 

def DrawMove(board):
    pass
```

I need to make `DrawMove(board)` randomly pick a free field and assign that to `'X'`, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Some help would be appreciated as I am still a beginner, I don't know all the little tricks to do stuff in Python yet. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you know how to make a random selection at all? Or is something else preventing you from solving this?

Comment: What does DrawMove do? Could you provide more details? Is it supposed to draw the x's? And are you asking for the function itself?